# Building a Portfolio and need some direction

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field

I'm still new to WordPress so bear with me. I'm building a portfolio in WordPress and one of the goals I have is to display individual work items by type: website, print piece, video, etc…

But alongside those, I also want to post "case studies" where I can pull in those same existing individual work items like building blocks to tell a bigger story if it's by the same client. So case studies are sort of like a Voltron, or superset of my existing work posts in a concatenated form.

If each of the work posts needed their own unique template—because we don't want the same fields for a tv project, as we do a website project. Would I need a custom post type for each individual type of work?

And then how would I go about concatenating work posts into case studies post types?

Hope I provided enough details. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

More or less you got two decision points here.

### Are “types” of work items CPTs or terms of taxonomy?

While from the start it sounds more like terms (they are all work items, but of different types) the latter requirement of different fields brings them closer to multiple CPTs in my opinion.

I don't think this is clear cut here, either could work. Personally if editor/fields are different then multiple CPTs make more sense to me.

### What case studies even are?

This is trickier. You need to pick individual items, of different types, and likely put them into specific order. Taxonomy is closest WP has for grouping, but it won't do well for tight control of what is happening *inside* group. It only defines being in or out.

Likely this calls for: CPT and post relationships. Problem is WP absolutely refuses to do post relationships, so you have to bring in a lib for that. Or just fake relationships convincingly.

So overall the first part is more of a picking direction thing. The second is more involved and custom, than just using native core functionality.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond to my question, Rarst. Which lib would you recommend to handle the post relationships?

Comment: The staple is Posts 2 Posts, but original developer moved on so there are some competitors around.